# Can you create a new wpdb that connects to an SQL (not MYSQL) database?

Tags: wpdb

I've been trying to do: $mydb = new wpdb(*SQL Database info*);

Is there a way to check whether the database connection was established? It doesn't seem to be working since $mydb->get_results(*query*) doesn't return anything, but I get no errors so I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

As per the WordPress documentation you cannot connect to another DB using `wpdb`.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

You best bet is to connect to the DB separately.